# Comparing two arrays containing strings?

Tags: c#

I have a text file that I wish to read and split into words.

I have a `RichTextBox` that I will get the text from and split into words also.

I want to be able to compare the words in the two arrays and then display a message.

How can I do this in c#?

Answer (score 2):

You can put words that you get from the text file into a `HashSet` and the ones you get from the ricktextbox1 to another `HashSet` and intersect them.

```
var set1 = new HashSet<string>(words1);
var set2 = new HashSet<string>(words2);
set1.IntersectWith(set2);
```

By the way, HashSet class is introduced with .Net 3.5

Answer (score 0):

HashSet

Answer (score 0):

You can always go with the brute force, going through the words from one array and checking if they are in the other. For every string you find in both arrays you mark the string or copy it into a separate array for strings that are in both of the arrays. When you finish you just print/count the strings in the new array.

Please note that this is very a slow approach and there are better ways of doing this out there, however you didn't mention speed was of the essence, and this will get you there.

You could try doing this with a HashSet (as Josh Einstein recommended), I am not familiar with that collection but a quick search tells me that it could work very well.